# Entity Framework create entity with collection

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I'm making C# EF Core application with PostgreSQL DB.
I have the following context and entities:

```
public class NpgsqlDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

After applying migration and running the application the tables are created, but creating request causes exceptions about duplicate keys.
When I open DBeaver I can see that EF created Tags table with a column called requestid.[image]

So if I try to insert new request object, I'm getting exception.
By the logic, I want to have set of Tags, and each Request can have zero, one or many of tags.

What should I change to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

By defining the relationship the way you have, EF is assuming that the relationship is one-to-many between Request and Tag, so it put a RequestId on the Tag table. Taking a guess at your intended schema, you probably want a many-to-many relationship where one request can have 0 or more tags associated to it, but a tag may be associated to 0 or many requests.

This requires a joining table, something like RequestTags containing a RequestId and TagId to represent the relationship. EF can map this without requiring a RequestTag entity, so Request can still use the relationship through a collection of Tags, and Tag may, or may not have a collection of Requests. The simplest solution would be to add:

```
public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
```

... to your Tag entity and EF will wire this up automatically by convention. If you don't want/need the Requests from the Tag side then you will need to configure EF to know that you intend to have a many-to-many relationship. This can either be during the DbContext OnModelCreating, or using an EntityConfiguration.

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Request>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("RequestTags"));
```

Details on managing relationships are pretty well documented from Microsoft at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

If instead you do intend tags to be in a one-to-many relationship with Requests, then the RequestId on the Tag table is correct. A specific tag can only be associated with a single Request. This means if you have a Tag called "Red", and you go to Request ID #1 and want to associate it with the tag "Red" that tag's Request ID would be "1". Other tags associated to that Request would also get a Request ID  of 1; So EF can know to load all Tags with a Request ID of 1 to build that request's Tags collection. Now the issue is if you want Request ID #2 to be associated with a "Red" tag. This would need to be a Tag with a different TagID than the other "Red" tag since that one is associated with Request #1. The many-to-many relationship would allow a single "Red" tag to be shared by both Request ID #1 and #2. This is useful for finding all requests associated to a particular tag record.

The error you are getting about duplicate data or tracked references is because EF works closely with References to entities and if you have multiple references containing the exact same data, EF will start throwing exceptions because it is already tracking references with those IDs, or if it isn't you can end up with unique constraint violations on PKs and other indexes if you tell EF to do something like insert a new record for an untracked reference.

To work out your specific errors you should extend your question to outline the code you are using to populate the entities and relationships that is generating the error.